# Jenkins API is giving access denied error

Tags: api, authentication, jenkins, curl, jenkins-api

When I use jenkins get api from browser, it works perfectly...

But when i hit api using curl it is giving below error...

Curl command:
curl -u JENKINS_USER_ID:TOKEN JENKINS_API_URL

```
Access Denied... <User> is missing the Overall/Read permission.
```

Comment: you should check in the dev console of your browser how the request is made (headers?) and share the curl command command you use so that we can see what is missing (looks like authentication issue...)

Comment: curl -u <JENKINS_USER_ID>:<TOKEN> JENKINS_API_URL